# Mysql Php Average of temperature reads divided by hour

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have a MYSQL DB with two columns, one is the temperature and the other one is the time in which the temperatura was read, like http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1860064 .
The temperature USUALLY have a 5minutes difference between reads, but this is not always with this time gap.

What I need to figure out is a algorithm to read all the values and save the average of every hour of read, so temperature will be saved on the db with one temperature per hour, 24 reads per day, and it would save in another db's table.

For example:

[image]

It would save with the average temperature and with the date 2012-10-07 10:00:00,

Was I clear?

Comment: What have you come up with so far? Where do you hit the road block? That is usually needed for a question, otherwise you need to wait and hope that someones knows it vs. the time it takes until your question gets closed. So feel free to add your (pseudo) code. And welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do this with just a query. If you need the results stored in the database you'll need your own inserts but this will get you the data you're looking for.

```
SELECT AVG(temperature),HOUR(read_time) as read_hour FROM temperature_reads WHERE DATE(read_time) = '2012-10-06' GROUP BY read_hour
```

You can swap the `2012-10-06` part out for whatever date you are looking at.

**Edit:** Here it is updated with your info:

```
SELECT AVG(temperatura),HOUR(data) as read_hour FROM leituras WHERE DATE(read_time) = '2012-10-06' GROUP BY read_hour
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: The table is called 'leituras', temperatures field is 'temperatura' and hour is called 'data', how would that fit in there? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is without filtering any day and including the whole day and hour on the grouping clause:

```
SELECT AVG(temperature),
       DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y %H') day_hour_read
  FROM TABLE
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y %H')
```